# mysql bulk delete

Tags: mysql, database, delete-row

I'm doing bulk delete in MySQL and it works well when I do 100 records however it fails with syntax error thing.

My goal is to do 10K records in every delete statement.

I'm not sure if it has to do with memory settings for MySQL.

Comment: can't you drop and recreate the table?

Comment: Fails with syntax error thing. Yeah I know exactly what you mean there....

Comment: what's your query?  post the SQL and we might be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a SQL editor, you may need to enable a particular setting to do large deletes.  For example, in MySQL Workbench, it's this:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
-- DELETE statement goes here
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Comment: Hey Jeff;
so you are saying that this SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATE should be set to 0 then run my script then set it back to 1? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1007727 Yes, if you're using MySQL Workbench to run it.  The syntax may be different depending on which IDE you're using.